# Conditional parameter type based on another parameters' value

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to assign a type to a functions' parameter, based on the value of another parameter?

```
type EmployeeType = {
 // ...
}

type EmployerType = {
 // ...
}


enum UserType {
    Employee = 'employee',
    Employer = 'employer'
}

function createUser(type: UserType, properties: EmployeeType | EmployerType) {
 // ...
}
```

On the above example, I would like to assign the respective type to `properties` based on the value of the `type` parameter.

One alternative to this would be to create different functions but in a more complicated scenario of more user types with more extensive names could result in very unreadable function names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution here is to use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads). Consider:

```
function createUser(type: UserType.Employee, properties: EmployeeType): void 
function createUser(type: UserType.Employer, properties: EmployerType): void
function createUser(type: UserType, properties: EmployeeType | EmployerType) {
 // ...
}
```

Thanks to overloads, we can make many type definitions which will be a guide for TS how functions arguments types should behave for the caller. Pay attention that the final definition is working with the whole spectrum available.

`void` return is here only as an example return type.

Comment: Thank you! I knew about method overloading but not how to work with the enums.